# How do you print or capture the current module name?

Tags: d

I want to print the module name of my main source file in that source file. I tried this:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits; // moduleName template

int main(string[] args)
{
    writeln("The module name is: ",moduleName!moduleName);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it prints:

> The module name is: std.traits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moduleName template description is:

> Get the module name (including package) for the given symbol.

So `moduleName!moduleName` should give `std.traits`.

Just replace the template argument with any other symbol to get it's module name.

For example `writeln(moduleName!main)`.

Another way is using `writeln(__MODULE__)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `__MODULE__` is the way to go. It's a special token, like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, which means it'll get expanded at the call site. See [the specs for some example](https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#specialkeywords).